# Vora Base can not deployed on Cloudera

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, vora

we want to install SAP HANA Vora 1.2 on a Cloudera Cluster.
Cluster specification:

- Cennt OS 6.7
- CDH 5.6.0
- HDFS 2.6.0

We have followed the installation guide and did **every** step.
But when it comes to "Add a new Service" --> "Vora Base" we get this error message:
[Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1qYi.jpg)

It seems like the service can not deploy it's configuration file.

Please help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CentOS is not a supported operating system. Therefore the deployment of the base services will fail. Please see the [Vora Product Availability Matrix (PAM)](https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/pam/pam.html#pvnr=73555000100900000415): currently only certain versions of RHEL and SLES are supported.
The Vora team is working on adding additional operating systems in future versions.